# Deleting rows from Pandas Dataframe if the sum is zero

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe which looks something like this

```
**FirstName MiddleName  LastName    Date    Value1  Value2  Value3**
first1  middle1 last1   1/31/2020   51  80  19
first1  middle1 last1   2/29/2020   14  44  56
first1  middle1 last1   3/31/2020   0   0   0
first1  middle1 last1   4/30/2020   57  96  40
first1  middle1 last1   5/31/2020   0   0   0
first1  middle1 last1   6/30/2020   58  65  3
first1  middle1 last1   7/31/2020   0   0   0
first1  middle1 last1   8/31/2020   1   34  4
first1  middle1 last1   9/30/2020   0   0   0
first1  middle1 last1   10/31/2020  40  38  53
first1  middle1 last1   11/30/2020  0   0   0
first1  middle1 last1   12/31/2020  93  65  41
first1  middle1 last1   1/31/2021   0   0   0
first1  middle1 last1   2/28/2021   3   43  0
first1  middle1 last1   3/31/2021   0   0   0
first1  middle1 last1   4/30/2021   46  61  52
*first2 middle2 last2   1/31/2020   0   0   0
first2  middle2 last2   2/29/2020   0   0   0
first2  middle2 last2   3/31/2020   0   0   0
first2  middle2 last2   4/30/2020   0   0   0
first2  middle2 last2   5/31/2020   0   0   0
first2  middle2 last2   6/30/2020   0   0   0
first2  middle2 last2   7/31/2020   0   0   0
first2  middle2 last2   8/31/2020   0   0   0
first2  middle2 last2   9/30/2020   0   0   0
first2  middle2 last2   10/31/2020  0   0   0
first2  middle2 last2   11/30/2020  0   0   0
first2  middle2 last2   12/31/2020  0   0   0
first2  middle2 last2   1/31/2021   0   0   0
first2  middle2 last2   2/28/2021   0   0   0
first2  middle2 last2   3/31/2021   0   0   0
first2  middle2 last2   4/30/2021   0   0   0
first2  middle2 last2   5/31/2021   0   0   0
first2  middle2 last2   6/30/2021   0   0   0*
first3  middle3 last3   4/30/2020   5   63  30
first3  middle3 last3   5/31/2020   45  22  7
first3  middle3 last3   6/30/2020   76  2   33
first3  middle3 last3   7/31/2020   0   0   0
first3  middle3 last3   8/31/2020   81  25  52
first3  middle3 last3   9/30/2020   55  3   32
first3  middle3 last3   10/31/2020  0   0   0
first3  middle3 last3   11/30/2020  46  45  80
first3  middle3 last3   12/31/2020  17  81  74
first3  middle3 last3   1/31/2021   98  6   55
```

I want to delete all the rows from this dataframe with **FirstName:first2** since all the values associated for this name are zeroes.

I tried this multistep approach to first get the sum of all the columns in a given row, then extract only the rows where the sum is zero.

```
# find row wise max value           
df['Sum'] = df[['Value1',  'Value2', 'Value3']].sum(axis = 1)

# filter rows from groups
df_check = df.loc[df.groupby('FirstName')['Sum'].idxmax()].reset_index()

df_check = df_check.loc[dfcheck['Sum']==0]
```

I was planning on comparing two dataframes to delete the **firstName** entries found in **df_check** from **df**. Which is where I am stuck.

Also maybe there is a simpler approach to the above problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC, try:

```
df[df.groupby('FirstName')[['Value1','Value2', 'Value3']].transform('any').any(axis=1)]
```

Output:

```
   FirstName MiddleName LastName        Date  Value1  Value2  Value3
0     first1    middle1    last1   1/31/2020      51      80      19
1     first1    middle1    last1   2/29/2020      14      44      56
2     first1    middle1    last1   3/31/2020       0       0       0
3     first1    middle1    last1   4/30/2020      57      96      40
4     first1    middle1    last1   5/31/2020       0       0       0
5     first1    middle1    last1   6/30/2020      58      65       3
6     first1    middle1    last1   7/31/2020       0       0       0
7     first1    middle1    last1   8/31/2020       1      34       4
8     first1    middle1    last1   9/30/2020       0       0       0
9     first1    middle1    last1  10/31/2020      40      38      53
10    first1    middle1    last1  11/30/2020       0       0       0
11    first1    middle1    last1  12/31/2020      93      65      41
12    first1    middle1    last1   1/31/2021       0       0       0
13    first1    middle1    last1   2/28/2021       3      43       0
14    first1    middle1    last1   3/31/2021       0       0       0
15    first1    middle1    last1   4/30/2021      46      61      52
34    first3    middle3    last3   4/30/2020       5      63      30
35    first3    middle3    last3   5/31/2020      45      22       7
36    first3    middle3    last3   6/30/2020      76       2      33
37    first3    middle3    last3   7/31/2020       0       0       0
38    first3    middle3    last3   8/31/2020      81      25      52
39    first3    middle3    last3   9/30/2020      55       3      32
40    first3    middle3    last3  10/31/2020       0       0       0
41    first3    middle3    last3  11/30/2020      46      45      80
42    first3    middle3    last3  12/31/2020      17      81      74
43    first3    middle3    last3   1/31/2021      98       6      55
```

Comment: It seems to working perfectly. Is there a way to extract the information of which names were dropped from the dataframe?. In this case, first2

Answer (score 0):

you can use `.drop()` function of dataframe
`df.drop(["first2"], inplace = True)`

But you can use this only if your FirstName Column is an index column.
So if your FirstName is not index column use this

`df.set_index("FirstName", inplace = True)`

Comment: First I need to check if the values column are all indeed zero before deciding what to drop

Comment: You can apply condition on the first argument so instead of "FirstName" use `df[df[FirstName]=='first2' and df[value1]==0 and df[value2]==0 and df[value3]==0].index`

Comment: [link](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/drop-rows-from-the-dataframe-based-on-certain-condition-applied-on-a-column/) use this link for reference